# Javafx remove quick white screen on app start

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Using javafx 7 update 60.
OS: Windows 7.

I've just taken helloworld from there
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm

and changed background of root pane to red.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000;");
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And while window is showing up, I can see its background is white, and after a moment switches to red. How can I remove this white screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so what you're seeing is the actual stage background. The primaryStage has it's own white background which you are seeing a split second before the scene is loaded. There's no real way around this unless you set the stage's background to transparent but that also makes the entire stage transparent including the exit button so you have to have a way for the user to exit your program.

Comment: That's right answer. I've discovered. Only transparent stage.
Do you know if they fixed it in JavaFX8?

Comment: Nope that's what I'm using. Maybe you could set the stage style to transparent, set a timer, add the scene, and then change the style back to normal. Weird problem but I've encountered this as well.

Comment: I've done somethings like this. Generally in my app I need two modes: fullscreen and windowed. So.. I've made two stages: transparent for fullscreen and decorated for windowed. Injected same scene to first. And the just switch between them. :)
That's because style for stage cannot be changed.

Comment: That's the right solution. When the app goes full screen you could have an exit button that you hard code in. My full screen apps are always transparent stages.

Answer (score 1):

The `Stage` you create in the first place has a solid white background, as said [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html). You cannot change the `StageStyle` of a `Stage`. 
An easy way to hide this background while your nodes are loading is to change the opacity of the `Stage` to 0 and then revert it back to 1 once the `Stage` is shown.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setOpacity(0.0);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000;");
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setOpacity(1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite this being a Zombie question, I will post my answer still .
Been having the same issue with my App though this time round instead of white it's been black(My Scene is transparent), so I landed here and all solutions suggested didn't work for me.

So I changed my Scene's fill from `Color.TRANSPARENT` to `null` and this solved it for me.

Here's my MRE:

```
public class MRE extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root.load(), 300, 200);

    scene.setFill(null); // Set scene fill to null so scene background doesn't show.

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```